# Combine values of two tables based on hour in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, inner-join, aggregate-functions, talend

I have two tables in postgresql. I need to add the columns of the tables based on per hour. I have the join columns as type in both the tables & also timestamp columns but those values are for 30mins. I need to add those values(levels & offers)from both the tables for an hour. Can this be done in Talend or Postgresql?
The fiddle below has the fields from both the tables. The image shows the expected output from both the tables after joining.
Here is the SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/228d3

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439152/sum-of-a-fields-in-hourly-in-talend

Comment: this is the combined values... the other one is sum of those values